# How to prevent scrolling? (cross-browser workaround)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, cross-browser

## Problem or question

I want to prevent *actual* scrolling of an element but I do want the benefits of a scrollbar (so some things will not have to be done programmatically with some JavaScript instead of browser handling things for us).

Is there anyone who has a better or improved solution for this? Any help's much appreciated.

## Update 13-03-2017

I have finally come up with an answer that seems to work (tested using) IE11, Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Chrome for Android and Firefox for Android.

So one can **disregard the rest of this question or problem description**.

## Update 12-03-2017

Found a way to toggle (prevent) scrolling across IE 11, Edge, Firefox, Chrome and Firefox for Android. Though it does not really work quite well (really laggy) in Chrome for Android. Anyone know why?

This is a summary of my solution (12-03-2017) but **Chrome for Android seems to not like it (!)**. Please help improve on this solution (or maybe there is a better way different from this particular solution?).

- One `div` with the scrolling content which has `position: fixed` (`#scrollsviascrolldistract` in my code).
- One `div` with the same amount of height as the scrolling content `div` which has `position: absolute` (or maybe `position: relative` when preferable). This is `#scrolldistract` in the embedded code sample.
- Call `window.requestAnimationFrame` with a callback function which adjusts `marginTop` value of the scrolling content `div` (`#scrollsviascrolldistract`) in relation to the current `scrollTop` value of the window (using negative margin for this).
- Then to excert control and prevent scrolling one can just not update this `marginTop` value to make the scrolling content `div` not be affected by current scrollbar position.

Tested below code snippet in IE 11, Edge, Firefox and Chrome (which work alright) and Chrome for Android (does not like it) and also tested Firefox for Android (does like it). Seems to work a lot better than using two `div` elements with `position: fixed`.

```js
var scrollDisabled = false;

function toggleScroll() {
  scrollDisabled = !scrollDisabled;
}

function doScroll() {
  var st;
  if (!scrollDisabled) {
    $("#scrollsviascrolldistract").css("marginTop", -$(window).scrollTop());
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(doScroll);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(doScroll);

$("#scrolltoggler").on('click', toggleScroll);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#scrollsviascrolldistract {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

#scrolldistract {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 6000px;
}

.red,
.blue {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scrolldistract">
  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" height="6000">
</div>

<div id="scrollsviascrolldistract">
  <div class="red">BEGIN</div>
  <div class="blue"><button id="scrolltoggler">Toggle Scroll On/Off</button></div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>

  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">END</div>
</div>
```

## Earlier solution (please disregard 12-03-2017; see updated solution)

So I make one element scroll but do not make it visible. I put a spacer image inside it to fill it to the proper height.

Then cross-browser problems arise.

## Earlier solution - What works and what does not?

### Chrome

- Scrolling via mouse or scrollbar works.
- Even focus() works so scrolling using keys is immediately possible.

### Chrome for Android

- Scrolling works via touch (as it should).

### Firefox

- Ctrl+PageUp/Ctrl+PageDown switches tab and disables scrolling until you grab the scrollbar.
- Scrolling via keys work, but one has to click in the background area for it to grab focus.

### Firefox for Android

- Total disaster: stops scrolling after a bit of scrolling. Do not know why.

### Edge

- Seems to work except for focus(). Need to click somewhere in the document (red/blue blocks or background).

### Internet Explorer 11

- Works only via mouse. Cannot grab focus, not even manually, to use keys to scroll.

## Code and such

Demo lives here:
https://jsfiddle.net/hn63z0jt/

Some HTML5 (with proper DOCTYPE):

```
<div id="scrollsviascrolldistract">
  <div class="red">BEGIN</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>

  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">END</div>
</div>
```

Some CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#scrollsviascrolldistract {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

#scrolldistract {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  z-index: 999;
}

.red, .blue {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Some JavaScript (using jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    var $window = $(window);
    var $scrollsviascrolldistract = $('#scrollsviascrolldistract');
    var $scrolldistract = $('#scrolldistract');

    $scrolldistract.focus();

    $scrolldistract.on('scroll', function() {
      var scrollTop = $scrolldistract.scrollTop();
      $scrollsviascrolldistract.css('marginTop', -scrollTop);
    });
});
```

Comment: May I ask what exactly drove you to such great lengths to hijack default scrolling behavior?

Comment: Change to `position: absolute`, drop the script and it will work perfect everywhere

Comment: @gyre: I want to use a scroll-linked effect. Among other things I've tried ScrollMagic and some part works but I also want to use scrolled distance for other effect (changing opacity of one element) *while that element along with parent container stay visible* and as such scrolling of that element and parent container must stop (be sticky in other words). I have tried things such as stickyJS too which does not work for elements which have more height than browser viewport height (because of limitations of 'position: fixed').

Comment: @LGSon: it depends what one is referring to with the 'it' in your comment. I need to use scrolling distance to add or subtract opacity for an element instead of scrolling that distance for that element (and its parent container). See also my comment directed at gyre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now ready to answer my own question.

So here's a way to toggle (prevent) scrolling:

- One `div` with the scrolling content which has `position: fixed` (`#scrollsviascrolldistract` in my code).
- One `div` with the same amount of height as the scrolling content `div` which has `position: absolute` (or maybe `position: relative` when preferable). This is `#scrolldistract` in the embedded code sample.
- Call `window.requestAnimationFrame` with a callback function which adjusts `marginTop` value of a puller `div` (called `#puller` here) which should be the first child of the scrolling content `div` (`#scrollsviascrolldistract`) in relation to the current `scrollTop` value of the window (using negative margin for this). At first I thought that I could just pull up the scrolling content itself (change `marginTop` of `#scrollsviascrolldistract`) but that does not work in some browsers.
- Then to excert control and prevent scrolling one can just not update this `marginTop` value to make the scrolling content `div` not be affected by current scrollbar position.

Tested below code snippet in IE 11, Edge, Firefox and Chrome and also in Chrome for Android and Firefox for Android. Seems to work a lot better than using two `div` elements with `position: fixed`.

```js
$(function() {
  var scrollDisabled = false;
  var $window = $(window);

  function doScroll() {
    var st = $window.scrollTop();
    if (!scrollDisabled) {
      console.log(st);
      if (st > 6000 - $window.innerHeight()) {
        $("#puller").css("marginTop", -(6000 - $window.innerHeight()));
      } else {
        $("#puller").css("marginTop", -st);
      }
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(doScroll);
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(doScroll);

  $("#scrolltoggler").on('click', function(e) {
    scrollDisabled = !scrollDisabled;
  });
});
```

```css
#scrollsviascrolldistract {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

#scrolldistract {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6000px;
}

#puller {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.red,
.blue {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: auto !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scrolldistract">
  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" width="1" height="6000">
</div>


<div id="scrollsviascrolldistract">
  <div id="puller"></div>
  <div class="red">BEGIN</div>
  <div class="blue"><button id="scrolltoggler">Toggle Scroll On/Off</button></div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>

  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">END</div>
</div>
```